# Catch undefined module function calls and process it within the module

Tags: python, module

My `my_module` has just 1 function called `f`.

So

```
import my_module
my_module.f()
```

is a valid code.

But I want to wrap undefined function calls the way `my_module.f()` is called instead. And I want to do it by default without any exta-code outside the module, i.e. I want to put all the wrapping code inside `my_module`. So when I do

```
import my_module
my_module.this_function_is_not_defined()
```

the python will not raise an exception, but call `my_module.f()` instead.

It's kind of overriding `__getattr__` of the class or `__getitem__` of the dict.

Is it possible to do it within the module?

Kind of

```
globals().__getitem__ = lambda self, x: self.__getitem__ if self.__contains__(x) else f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `__getattr__` on a module just like on a class. Assuming that we have the following in `my_module.py`:

```
def f():
    print('hello world')

def __getattr__(attr):
    return f
```

We can use it like this:

```
>>> import my_module
>>> my_module.bar()
hello world
>>> my_module.this_function_is_not_defined()
hello world
```

Etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And do you know how to call `__getattribute__(attr)` within `__getattr__(attr)`?The point that in case the attribute was not found, I want to initilize the module and try to search again.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Can you describe how the *behavior* you want is different from the behavior you get with the code in this answer?

Comment: Seems that this works:
```
def __getattr__(attr):
    if not config.is_loaded:
        init()
        if attr in globals():
            return globals()[attr]
        else:
            pass
    else:
        raise AttributeError(f"No attribute '{attr}'")

```